# Matching in a Dynamic Erdős–Rényi graph

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, poisson-distribution, coupling

Suppose that nodes arrive to the two sides (left and right) of a bipartite graph $G$ dynamically according to independent Poisson processes with rate $1$ and $n>1$, respectively.  Every node *departs* the graph with rate 1 (i.e., there's an independent exponential distribution for every node that gives how long after the node's arrival it departs the graph). A node on the left is adjacent to a node on the right independently with probability $p$. Nodes are *matched* to each other greedily: upon the arrival of a node $v$, if there's another node in the graph adjacent to $v$, then the two nodes are matched and removed from the graph immediately.

*Let $D_p$ denote the steady state distribution of the number of nodes on the right side. Then, $D_p$ stochastically dominates $D_1$.*

The above claim is very intuitive: if $p=1$, nodes will be matched more quickly, thus there'll be less nodes in the graph. I have tried coupling the Markov chains to prove it, but I face a difficulty: if $p<1$, more nodes will be accumulated on the left side, which can later lead to a higher number of matches (and thereby a lower number of nodes!). This breaks the couplings that I could think of. I'd appreciate any suggestions or ideas.

Comment: A probably easier claim to prove is the same but for when nodes on the left depart the graph with rate $0$ (instead of 1). That is, the nodes on the left never depart the graph. The same issue with the coupling arises here as well.

Comment: I really can't understand your question, sorry. Do you start off with a an actual graph, i.e. vertices and edges? What arrives and goes? Maybe I don't know what "node" means. And in the greedy matching, what if there are multiple things adjacent to $v$?

Comment: Nodes are the same thing as vertices. Suppose you start with an empty graph. nodes arrive over time according to Poisson processes described above, and their adjacency is determined randomly (every two nodes on the two sides are adjacent independently with probability p) If there are multiple nodes adjacent to v, then pick one uniformly at random. Hope this is clear now.. let me know if not. And thanks for your interest!

Comment: thanks for your response. much more is clear to me now, but not everything. The end is really confusing me. "Nodes are matched to each other greedily: upon the arrival of a node , if there's another node in the graph adjacent to , then the two nodes are matched and removed from the graph immediately." First of all, if I understand correctly, a node $v$ arrives, and then its adjacencies are determined? Second, is this matching independent of the departures?

Comment: Maybe I understand. Tell me if this is all correct. You can pretend the nodes arrive one by one (according to the Poisson processes with rates $1$ and $n$). Each time a node $v$ arrives, you go through the other nodes one by one, with each other node being adjacent to $v$ with probability $p$, and the first time you get an adjacency, say with $v'$, you get rid of $v$ and $v'$; if you get no adjacencies, $v$ just stays there. And then you also have departures: every vertex in the graph (that wasn't immediately matched with another vertex and thrown away), departs according to a Poisson process.

Comment: Actually, there's one thing not making sense: you say "there's an independent exponential distribution for every node that gives how long after the node's arrival it departs the graph". But I think this is false, since that node can leave due to a matching, right?

Comment: Oops, meant to say "departs according to an independent exponential distribution" instead of "departs according to a Poisson process" at the end of my second to last (now third to last) comment.

Comment: Nodes can be *removed* from the graph in two ways: they can get matched to another node,  or they may `depart' due to their independent exponential random variable (think of this exponential variable as a clock, when the clock ticks, the node departs. if a node is already removed from the graph because it got matched, then the clock's tick doesn't really affect anything). Is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes, thanks! ${}{}$